# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol - unseen instance of the issue

Tags: c++

Im having a error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol problem.

I have 2 files and im moving them to a shared location so 2 different projects can use class.
There are other classes in there like this.

The problem is that when i call the class from the main of one of the projects im getting

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CProcessCommandLine::~CProcessCommandLine(void)" (??1CProcessCommandLine@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall CProcessCommandLine::Wait(void)const " (?Wait@CProcessCommandLine@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > const & __thiscall CProcessCommandLine::getTargetNamesVect(void)" (?getTargetNamesVect@CProcessCommandLine@@QAEABV?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CProcessCommandLine::CProcessCommandLine(void)" (??0CProcessCommandLine@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
```

When i open the header file and right click on one of the functions and go to go to definition it doesnt go to the definition in the .cpp. When i right click on a function in the .cpp and say go to definition it says "The symbol  is not defined".

Anyone know why this might be happening? Both the .h and .cpp are in the same location and that location is in the Additional Include Directories of the project

EDIT:

The following code exists in other files in this folder:

```
#ifdef PROJ1
#include "class1.h"
#elif PROJ2
#include "class2.h"
#endif
```

Ive never seen these things before. They are used in the code but only to include a correct header depending on which project it is used in. The above is in the .cpp of other classes in this folder. So i put it in here. But in other classes the project it doesnt belong to is greyed out. When i put it into the .h it greys out the correct header. But for some reason this .cpp isnt being recognized as part of the project.

Comment: I don't think you are linking against the objects/library are you?

Comment: maybe not. Id of thought that gets done along with everything else during compilation/linking, but apparently not. Where would the objects/library be?

Answer (score 0):

If your function belongs to a different module than the one you're building, you'll have to export the classes:

```
#ifdef THIRD_MODULE
#define DLLIMPEXP _declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLIMPEXP _declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class DLLIMPEXP CProcessCommandLine
{
   //...
};
```

you build the project that defines this class with `THIRD_MODULE` defined.

This project will generate `.lib` file, which you have to add to the additional dependencies in the linker settings of your main project.

Comment: @discodowney your edit doesn't affect my answer. The `cpp` file is only part of one project (or at least it should be).

Comment: Im horribly lost here. Why is the header file okay then?

Comment: @discodowney I'm not sure what you mean. The cpp file is also okay. But you're not exporting your class. You can use the methods inside the same module, but they are not exported for outside use. If you want to use them in a different module, you have to export them.

Comment: what do you mean export them? When i say the .h file is okay, i mean is its being recognized as part of the project.

Comment: @discodowney header files are not compiled. They contain only the definition of classes. Exporting and linking is a big topic. Read this - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL

Comment: There is another class in the same location that is used in both projects that doesnt have any #ifdef......#endif though.

Comment: @discodowney maybe its methods are inlined. Maybe it's not used. Have you read the link?